Get Telegram User Profile via Telegram Bot API
Goal
I'm developing a game for Telegram using the Unity WebGL engine. My aim is to retrieve the Telegram user's profile information when they enter the game via Bot API.
Context
I've already set up a bot using BotFather on Telegram and created a web app that's linked to my web-based game.
Reference URLs
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api
Tried
I attempted to retrieve the user profile using the getUpdates function with an offset value. However, this method didn't return the individual user's profile as I had hoped. Instead, it only provided the profile information for the chat user.
